# Make raw_input() work with both pipes and arguments when wrapped in a .bat file

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to write a .bat wrapper around python code which could handle both argument and piped inputs. Arguments are no problem, but i as soon as i try to pipe an input i lose the ability to use raw_input to query the user and/or cause an EOFError. Here's an example below, lets call it **test.bat**. What could i change to the script below to let it handle both piped and argument inputs?

[EDIT] Thanks to Harry Johnston for the great suggestion, see code below for a rock solid method for getting user input with both pipes and arguments!

```
@echo off
rem = """
setlocal enableextensions
set PYTHON="C:/Python27/python.exe"
%PYTHON% -x "%~f0" %*
goto endofPython """


import os, stat, sys

# This effectively replaces raw_input()
def workaround(message):
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write(message)
        answer = ''
        with open('CON') as console:
            answer = console.readline().lower().strip()

        if answer == 'y' or answer == 'yes':
            return True
        elif answer == 'n' or answer == 'no':
            return False

mode = os.fstat(0).st_mode
if stat.S_ISFIFO(mode) or stat.S_ISREG(mode):
    print
    if workaround("Print STDIN? ([Y]es,[N]o)"):
        print
        print
        for x in sys.stdin:
            print 'STDIN: %s'%x.strip()

if sys.argv[1:]:
    print
    if workaround("Print ARGV? ([Y]es,[N]o)"):
        print
        for x in sys.argv[1:]:
            print 'ARGV : %s'%x

rem = """
:endofPython """
```

Comment: This would seem to be the expected behaviour.  Try using `open("CON")` to create a file object representing the console window.

Comment: @HarryJohnston still doesn't work sadly, same output as before

Comment: Input from CON shouldn't be redirected - it can't, in fact, unless Python is doing something completely absurd.  Can you show your code?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, test.bat described above is my code. If you're referring to your suggestion with open("CON"), i added that line right after my imports to test and it didn't change the outcome.

Comment: If that's the only change you made, of course it didn't affect anything.  You have to replace your calls to `raw_input` with calls that get input from the file object returned by `open("CON")`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sorry my bad. So your suggestion does work in the sense that the errors are gone, however in order to get the user input out of the object you have to ctrl-c out of it which isn't ideal, plus it always ends the script with a "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?". I'm updating the code so you can see what i've done

Comment: The `readlines` method reads data until you reach end of file.  Pressing Control-Z will probably terminate input without terminating the program entirely.  Or you could use `readline` to read just a single line, like `raw_input` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you can create a file object for reading data from the console (i.e., bypassing standard input redirection) using `open('CON')`.